# WP Toggle Plugin Needed - Paid or Free

Tags: wordpress, toggle, accordion

Can anyone suggest me a WP Plugin which can toggle like on this page? http://jedfoster.coma/Readmore.js/

The one I did with some CSS is not working fine in Chrome and IE here http://desertvethurricane.com

I am using Thrive-Squared theme, it does has a toggle but more of kind like FAQ works. A bold heading and toggle content under it. Shortcode ultimate plugin's toggles are kind of same. I need a toggle, which should have a READ MORE (content editable) button and when clicked, it should scroll to bottom and have a READ LESS button as shown in the example above.

Timely help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you edit the css?

Comment: I fixed it with collapse-o-matic free WP Plugin. In their complete documentation, they have solution for my above requirements.